# Python 3 | Closing Window on Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So pretty much this is the code I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
text = "Hello World"
theLabel = Label(root,text = text,font=("Arial",200),height = 100,)
theLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
time.sleep(5)
```

How can I close the window after the program sleeps for 5 seconds? I have tried `root.destroy()`
but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance, 
Fargo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have does **not** execute after `root.mainloop()`.

Even if you do a simple `print("Hello World")` statement after `root.mainloop()`, it wont execute until your Tkinter window closes.

This is because `root.mainloop()` is an infinte-loop, constantly running your tkinter window.

```
    root.mainloop() #Runs your tkinter window
    print("Hello World") #<-- Will not be executed until your root.mainloop() stops
```

---

So the question is: how do we get your **"closing the window after 5 seconds"** to work during `root.mainloop`...

The answer is through the use of `root.after(miliseconds,desiredFunction)`.

---

Here is your program with the desired effect of closing after 5 seconds:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
text = "Hello World"
theLabel = Label(root,text = text,font=("Arial",200),height = 100,)
theLabel.pack()

#after 5000 miliseconds(5 seconds) of root being 'alive', execute root.destroy()
root.after(5000, root.destroy) #notice no parenthesis () after destroy

root.mainloop()
```

---

Hopefully this is what you were looking for!

Comment: _"constantly running your tkinter window."_ isn't quite what happens. It doesn't "run" a window, it runs an event loop. Perhaps that is splitting hairs, but you make it sound like it runs your program over and over, which it does not. The code in your program executes once.